# how to write bulk of data into xml file from backend and i want to bind the xml file into list?

Tags: python, mysql, apache-flex, elips-studio

I want to write the bulk of data into xml file ,the data coming from the backend(mysql) using cgi by httpservice, read the xml file and bind it into list...
can anyone send the sample code for this?

Thank's in advance..

Comment: Sorry - are you nuts? "Buld of data" like 100.000 items of it? In memory? You think your program can handle that? This will blow out - tons of data transfer, and whatever client you use on the front end will possibly start using up all memory available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<mx:HTTPService url="backend-url.cgi" id="service"/>
<mx:List dataProvider="{service.lastResult.yourElementName}"/>
```

You should also

- Call `service.send()` from the Application's `creationComplete` handler
- Specify the `labelField`, `dataField` etc for the `List` as applicable